# Definition of the derivative of a real function in "Baby Rudin"

Tags: real-analysis

**In "Baby Rudin" the derivative of a real function is defined as follows.**

Let $f$ be defined (and real valued) on $[a,b]$. For any $x\in [a,b]$ form the quotient
$$
\phi(t)=\frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x} \quad (a<t<b, t\ne x),
$$
and define
$$
f'(x)=\lim \limits_{t\to x}\phi(t),
$$
provided this limit exists in accordance with Definition 4.1.

**Are there any objections against the following generalization?**

Let $f$ be defined (and real valued) on $E\subset\mathbb{R}$. For any $x\in E$, such that $x$ is a limit point of $E$, form the quotient
$$
\phi(t)=\frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x} \quad (t\in E, t\ne x),
$$
and define
$$
f'(x)=\lim \limits_{t\to x}\phi(t),
$$
provided this limit exists in accordance with Definition 4.1.

Comment: the second definition contains the first but, since usually one works with functions defined on open sets or intervals, it is more practical the first definition. Also, it doesnt need concepts like limit point.

Comment: Thanks! Just wanted to make sure there are no hidden problems with the generalization. The first definition does require concept of a limit point, since limit of a function is defined in terms of it. Although we could also redefine limit of a real function in terms of an interval.